# Getting & Managing/updating local built-in accounts for some Windows domain & standalone servers (vbscript)

Tags: windows, vbscript, accounts

**
Hi!
I was wondering if someone tried something similar, I have some code merged with a lot of glue...but as i'm a newby in vbs I can be sure that most of it is wrong. Basically I wanted to save a lot time during built-in admin accounts review /update with an automatic vbscript for this task.
I have like 6 account names and each one with an specific passwords. 
I'm not 100% sure of which local account name is being used into each server but that might be something that i will need to verify manually or try to see if I can use another file where this script will read the possible accounts names and passwords and use some kind of brute force
Here is what I have :**

**update 8-29-12 a (deleted)

**update 8-29-12 b  "THIS ONE IS WORKING..but i need to test & use cpau for NDC's"

```
Option Explicit

Dim strExcelPath, objExcel, objSheet, intRow, strUserDN, strPassword, comp
Dim objUser

' Spreadsheet file.
strExcelPath = "c:\List.xls"

' Bind to Excel object.
On Error Resume Next
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
If (Err.Number <> 0) Then
    On Error GoTo 0
    Wscript.Echo "Excel application not found."
    Wscript.Quit
End If
On Error GoTo 0

' Open spreadsheet.
On Error Resume Next
objExcel.Workbooks.Open strExcelPath
If (Err.Number <> 0) Then
    On Error GoTo 0
    Wscript.Echo "Spreadsheet cannot be opened: " & strExcelPath
    Wscript.Quit
End If
On Error GoTo 0

' Bind to worksheet.
Set objSheet = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)


intRow = 2
Do While objSheet.Cells(intRow, 1).Value <> ""
    comp = objSheet.Cells(intRow, 1).Value
    strUserDN = objSheet.Cells(intRow, 2).Value
    strPassword = objSheet.Cells(intRow, 3).Value
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objuser = GetObject ("WinNT://" & comp & "/" & strUserDN & ",user")
    If (Err.Number <> 0) Then
        On Error GoTo 0
        Wscript.Echo "Data NOT found: "
    Else
        objUser.SetPassword strPassword
        If (Err.Number <> 0) Then
            On Error GoTo 0
            Wscript.Echo "Password NOT set for: " & strUserDN
        Else


        End If
    End If
    intRow = intRow + 1
Loop

' Close the workbook.
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close

' Quit Excel.
objExcel.Application.Quit

Wscript.Echo "Done"
```

My option "B" could be start over using something like this:
@echo off

for /F "delims=" %%i in (servers.txt) do (
 psexec \%%i NET USER > %%i.txt
)

**

There might hundreds of ways to solve this and the my idea it's avoid having someone manually modifying the admin passwords for the servers listed and not listed in the AD after one month.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Is your question: Fix the errors?

Comment: Actually I just wanted to know if that's something already done (i don't mind using freeware tools as long as the work is automatic) ,but anything will help.

Comment: You need to simplify your question. If you need help with the code, reduce it down to simplest script that works, then add back pieces, fixing errors as you go and asking questions when you're stuck. If you're looking for a 3rd party tool, what exactly do you need it to do?

Comment: I guess that the best idea would be start over..I'm trying to compile a list of local built-in accounts from all the standalone servers W2K,W2K3 and W2K8 on the network. I know that part of this can be solved using psexec but in my case i have 6 possible local account names.Once i get that info i will need a function for updating the account passwords.

Answer (score 0):

This code will list the local users for one computer, specified by the variable `server`, and then print the user id of each user.

```
server = "YourServerName"
Set oComputer = GetObject("WinNT://" & server & "")
oComputer.Filter = Array("User")
For Each oUser in oComputer
  WScript.Echo oUser.Name
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

```
'Objective: check multiple servers for admin accounts status and report to html file

Set iFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesyStemObject") 
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesyStemObject") 

InputFile = WScript.Arguments.Named("servers")
if len(InputFile) < 1 then
    wscript.echo "Error: Servers Parameter not found" & vbCrLf
    show_usage
    wscript.quit
end if

Outputfile= InputFile & "_guest_admins_" + cstr(Month(now()))+"_"+cstr(day(now()))+".htm" 

if not ofso.FileExists(inputfile) then
    wscript.echo "Error: Server list file not Found."
    wscript.quit
end if

Set ofile = ofso.createTextFile(OutputFile, True) 
Set ifile = iFSO.OpenTextFile(inputfile) 

ofile.writeline "<html>" & html_head & "<body>"

    ofile.writeline "<table border=1 cellpadding=1 cellspacing=0>"
    ofile.writeline o 
    ofile.writeline "<tr><td>Hostname</td><td>User</td><td>Disabled</td><td>Locked</td><td>Expiration Date</td><td>Flags</td><td>BuiltIn</td></tr>"

Do until ifile.AtEndOfLine
Computer = ifile.ReadLine
if ping(Computer) then
            Builtin = ""
            if Check_WMI(Computer) then
                Builtin = GetBuiltInAccount(Computer)
            else
                Builtin = "WMI Fail"
            end if

            strt = now
            wscript.echo "Checking Users for server: " & Computer

            on error resume next

            Set objGroup = GetObject("WinNT://" & Computer & "/Administrators,group")

            if err.number <> 0 then
                wscript.echo "GetObject WinNT Failed"
                ofile.writeline "<tr><td>" & computer & "</td><td colspan=6 align=center>GetObject WinNT Fail: "& err.number &"</td></tr>"
            else            
                on error goto 0

                For Each objUser in objGroup.Members
                        ofile.writeline GetUserNT(computer, objUser.Name, Builtin)
                Next

                wscript.echo "Elapsed Time: " & datediff("s", strt, now) & " seconds"
            end if
else
    wscript.echo computer & " does not reply ping"
    ofile.writeline "<tr><td>" & computer & "</td><td colspan=6 align=center>No Ping Reply</td></tr>"
end if
Loop 
ofile.writeline "</table>"

ofile.writeline "</body></html>"

function ping(target)
    strComputer = "."
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set colPingedComputers = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_PingStatus Where Address = '"& target & "'")
    For each objComputer in colPingedComputers
      ' If the status code is Null or Not 0 then the ping failed
      If IsNull( objComputer.StatusCode ) Or objComputer.StatusCode <> 0 Then 
        ' Set the function to return Boolean FALSE
        Ping = False
      Else
        ' Set the function to return Boolean TRUE
        Ping = True
      End If
    Next
end function

sub show_usage
    wscript.echo "Usage:  cscript chkusers /servers:list.txt" & vbcrlf

    wscript.echo vbtab & "/servers Parameter is a Text File one Servername per Line" & vbcrlf

    wscript.echo "Notes:  This script generates an html report of server admin accounts."
    wscript.echo "  Results are saved in a file named + date + htm extension."
    wscript.echo "  Output example filename: list_guest_admins_" + cstr(Month(now()))+"_"+cstr(day(now()))+".htm"

end sub

Function Check_WMI(strServer)
    On Error Resume Next ' error handling off

    ' create object reference, connect to namespace root\default
    Set oCimOmId = GetObject("winmgmts:"& strServer & "\root\default:__cimomidentification=@")

    ' Test whether WMI is present or not.
    If Err <> 0 then
        Check_WMI= true
    else
        Check_WMI= false
    end if
    on error goto 0
end function

Sub EnumNameSpaces(strNameSpace)
    'call enumnamespaces("root")
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\" & strNameSpace)
    Set colNameSpaces = objWMIService.InstancesOf("__NAMESPACE")
    For Each objNameSpace In colNameSpaces
        Call EnumNameSpaces(strNameSpace & "\" & objNameSpace.Name)
    Next
End Sub

function CSS
tt = "<style type=""text/css"">" & vbcrlf
tt=tt & " body {font-family:Verdana;font-size: 10px;color: #49403B;background: #EFEFEF;}" & vbcrlf
tt=tt & "table {font-family:Verdana;font-size: 12px; empty-cells:show; }" & vbcrlf
tt=tt & "</style>"  & vbcrlf
CSS = tt
end function

function html_head
    tt="<head>" & vbcrlf
    tt=tt & CSS
    html_head = tt & "</head>" & vbcrlf
end function


function GetUserNT(strComputer, usr, bltin)
    Const ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD = &H10000

    o=""
    On Error Resume Next

    Set objUser = GetObject("WinNT:// " & strComputer & "/" & usr & " ")

    o=o& "<tr><td>"& strcomputer &"</td><td>"& usr &"</td>"

    if len(objUser.AccountDisabled) = 0 then exit function

    o=o& "<td>&nbsp;"& StrDisabled(objUser.AccountDisabled) &"</td>"
    o=o& "<td>&nbsp;"& StrLocked(objUser.IsAccountLocked) &"</td>"


    o=o& "<td>&nbsp;"
        o=o& objUser.Get("UserFlags") AND ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD
    o=o& "</td>"

    o=o& "<td>&nbsp;"
        o=o& objUser.AccountExpirationDate
    o=o& "</td>"

    if lcase(bltin) = lcase(usr) then
        o=o & "<td>&nbsp;Built-In</td>"
    elseif instr(bltin, "[[Fail]]") > 0 then
        o=o & "<td>&nbsp;"& bltin &"</td>"
    else
        o=o & "<td>&nbsp;</td>"
    end if

    o = o & "</tr>"

    GetUserNT = o
end function

function StrLocked(str)
    if str = "True" then
        StrLocked = "Locked"
    else
        StrLocked = "Unlocked"
    end if
end function

function StrDisabled(str)
    if str = "True" then
        StrDisabled = "Disabled"
    else
        StrDisabled = "Enabled"
    end if
end function

function GetUsers(strComputer,grp,usr)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_UserAccount Where name = '"& usr &"'")
    o=""
    For Each objItem in colItems
        o=o& "<tr>"
        o=o& "<td>" & strComputer & "</td>"
        o=o& "<td>" & grp & "</td>"
        o=o& "<td>" & objItem.AccountType & "</td>"
        o=o& "<td>" & objItem.Caption & "</td>"
        o=o& "<td>" & objItem.Description & "</td>"
        o=o& "<td>" & objItem.Disabled & "</td>"
        o=o& "<td>" & objItem.Domain & "</td>"
        o=o& "<td>" & objItem.FullName & "</td>"
        o=o& "<td>" & objItem.LocalAccount & "</td>"
        o=o& "<td>" & objItem.Lockout & "</td>"
        o=o& "<td>" & objItem.Name & "</td>"
        o=o& "<td>" & objItem.PasswordChangeable & "</td>"
        o=o& "<td>" & objItem.PasswordExpires & "</td>"
        o=o& "<td>" & objItem.PasswordRequired & "</td>"
        o=o& "<td>" & objItem.SID & "</td>"
        o=o& "<td>" & objItem.SIDType & "</td>"
        o=o& "<td>" & objItem.Status & "</td>"
        o=o& "</tr>"
    Next
    on error goto 0
    GetUsers = o
end function





Function getlcl(srvname)
    Set objComputer = GetObject("WinNT://" & srvname & "/Administrators,group")

 wscript.echo "Local Accounts on " & srvname
 wscript.echo "-------------------------------------------------"

    For Each objUser in objComputer.Members
        Wscript.Echo vbTab & objUser.Name
    Next

 wscript.echo "-------------------------------------------------"
end Function

function GetBuiltInAccount(strComputer)

    on error resume next
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    if err.number <> 0 then
        GetBuiltInAccout = "Get Object WMI [[Fail]]: " & err.number & ":: " & err.description
        err.clear
        exit function
    end if
    on error goto 0

    on error resume next
    Set colAccounts = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_UserAccount Where Domain = '" & strComputer & "'")

    if err.number <> 0 then
        GetBuiltInAccout = "WMI_ExecQuery [[Fail]]: " & err.number & ":: " & err.description
        err.clear
        exit function
    end if
    on error goto 0

    on error resume next
    For Each objAccount in colAccounts
        if err.number <> 0 then
            GetBuiltInAccout = "WMI_ExecQuery_ForEachAccount [[Fail]]: " & err.number & ":: " & err.description
            wscript.echo "WMI_ExecQuery_ForEachAccount [[Fail]]: " & err.number & ":: " & err.description
            err.clear
            exit function
        end if
        on error goto 0

        If Left (objAccount.SID, 6) = "S-1-5-" and Right(objAccount.SID, 4) = "-500" Then
            GetBuiltInAccount = objAccount.Name
            exit function

        End If
    Next
end function
```

---

Special instructions

For Domain servers:

### Create a batch/cmd file (something like admins.cmd) containing the line below:

cscript admin.vbs /servers:list.txt

For Standalone server:
-Download CPAU.exe

### Create a batch/cmd file (something like adminsNDC.cmd) conteninig the line below:

CPAU -u %COMPUTERNAME%\administrator -p mypassword -ex "cscript.exe Admins.vbs /servers:list.txt" -nowarn

---

-Local Admin report v1-

Instructions

For Domain servers:
1-Add the servers to be scaned into: "list.txt"
2-Run/create a scheduled task for "one" of the following files :
 admins.cmd <-------> (you will get: |Hostname|User| Disabled |Locked |Expiration Date| Flags |BuiltIn |)
3-Check the html report(you can sent it to excel through IE)

For a Standalone server:

1-Add the server to be scaned into: "list.txt"
2-Edit the account name  and password info into adminsNDC.cmd
3-Run adminsNDC.cmd  <-------> (you will get: |Hostname|User| Disabled |Locked |Expiration Date| Flags |BuiltIn |)
3-Check the html report

---

---

After getting a report of the servers and accounts, this script could be used to perform  password's update.

```
Option Explicit

Dim strExcelPath, objExcel, objSheet, intRow, strUserDN, strPassword, comp
Dim objUser

' Spreadsheet file.
strExcelPath = "c:\List.xls"

' Bind to Excel object.
On Error Resume Next
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
If (Err.Number <> 0) Then
    On Error GoTo 0
    Wscript.Echo "Excel application not found."
    Wscript.Quit
End If
On Error GoTo 0

' Open spreadsheet.
On Error Resume Next
objExcel.Workbooks.Open strExcelPath
If (Err.Number <> 0) Then
    On Error GoTo 0
    Wscript.Echo "Spreadsheet cannot be opened: " & strExcelPath
    Wscript.Quit
End If
On Error GoTo 0

' Bind to worksheet.
Set objSheet = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)


intRow = 2
Do While objSheet.Cells(intRow, 1).Value <> ""
    comp = objSheet.Cells(intRow, 1).Value
    strUserDN = objSheet.Cells(intRow, 2).Value
    strPassword = objSheet.Cells(intRow, 3).Value
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objuser = GetObject ("WinNT://" & comp & "/" & strUserDN & ",user")
    If (Err.Number <> 0) Then
        On Error GoTo 0
        Wscript.Echo "Data NOT found: "
    Else
        objUser.SetPassword strPassword
        If (Err.Number <> 0) Then
            On Error GoTo 0
            Wscript.Echo "Password NOT set for: " & strUserDN
        Else


        End If
    End If
    intRow = intRow + 1
Loop

' Close the workbook.
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close

' Quit Excel.
objExcel.Application.Quit

Wscript.Echo "Done"
```

Comment: You can use just one `FileSystemObject` object in your script for both writing and reading files. I usually use `Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesyStemObject")`.